# could not decode stream in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: streaming, clementine, internet-radio

When I want to play Radio Stream in Clementine, I get error:`could not decode stream.`

I installed w32codecs, but is not solved.

```
sudo apt-get -y install w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried other players?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open your terminal and install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad and/or gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse.

you can do that by

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
```

you can also use synaptic or software centre to install.

hope that helps.

Comment: Why are they called "bad"?!

Comment: @Tim http://askubuntu.com/questions/468875/plugins-ugly-and-bad