# GStreamer plugins: "ugly" and "bad"

Tags: gstreamer

Why are gstreamer plugins labeled as "bad" and "ugly"?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/splitup.html

> **gst-plugins-base**
>   a small and fixed set of plug-ins, covering a wide range of possible types of elements; these are continuously kept
>   up-to-date with any core changes during the development series.
>
> - We believe distributors can safely ship these plug-ins
> - People writing elements should base their code on these elements
> - These elements come with examples, documentation, and regression tests
>
> **gst-plugins-good**
>       a set of plug-ins that we consider to have good quality code, correct functionality, our preferred license (LGPL for the plug-in
>   code, LGPL or LGPL-compatible for the supporting library).
>
> - We believe distributors can safely ship these plug-ins
> - People writing elements should base their code on these elements
>
> **gst-plugins-ugly**
>   a set of plug-ins that have good quality and correct functionality, but distributing them might pose problems. The
>   license on either the plug-ins or the supporting libraries might not
>   be how we'd like. The code might be widely known to present patent
>   problems.
>
> - Distributors should check if they want/can ship these plug-ins
> - People writing elements should base their code on these elements
>
> **gst-plugins-bad**
>   a set of plug-ins that aren't up to par compared to the rest. They might be close to being good quality, but
>   they're missing something - be it a good code review, some
>   documentation, a set of tests, a real live maintainer, or some actual
>   wide use. If the blanks are filled in they might be upgraded to become
>   part of either gst-plugins-good or gst-plugins-ugly, depending on the
>   other factors.
>
> - If the plug-ins break, you can't complain - instead, you can fix the problem and send us a patch, or bribe someone into fixing them for you
> - New contributors can start here for things to work on

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the info. Very helpful. Reminds me, also, to add freedesktop.org to my reading list.