# Get gmusicbrowser to play .m4a music files?

Tags: 14.04, gstreamer, gmusicbrowser

What plugins do I need to install to get gmusicbrowser to play .m4a files?

I already installed gstreamer ugly, bad, good (what's up with those names??). Do I need anything else? gmusicbrowser keeps complaining that gstreamer is missing a plugin whenever I try to play a .m4a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably installed the gstreamer **1.0** plugins, but `gmusicbrowser` is still using their **0.10** versions even on 14.04.

To properly play/decode MPEG-4 AAC you need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Note: See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/468877/32239) to know why they are named like this.